# Javascript: sum all values of a table row in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

In my Chrome console, I have a table called ***data*** which has 23 rows and look like this: data table in Chrome console

[image]

Then I select the first row with `data[0]`, it looks like this: 
data[0]

[image]

My objective is to sum all the values of this row (and each row), how to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: what have you tried? If you show us your attempt we can help fix/alter it with you.

Comment: Actually I am new to javascript and stackoverflow so sorry if i am not clear. For example, I have many countries which i can access their values one by one: `data[0].Afghanistan` returns 1.2, `data[0].Albania` returns 1.3 etc. I would like to have the sum of all the countries values sum=1.2 +1.3 +... etc. If im not clear please do tell me

Comment: yes you should at least do some research on loops and attempt the solution. Stack Overflow isn't a place to come to have code written for you. When you have a problem with your loop you can edit your question with your attempt and then we can start helping you.

Comment: thank u for your answer I'll do that ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sum the values in each row of `data`, except the `hour` value, which is a date.

```
var sums = Array.prototype.slice.call(data, 0).map(function(item) {
  return Object.keys(item)
    .filter(function (key) { return key !== 'hour'})
    .reduce(function(total, key) {
      return total + item[key]
    }, 0)
})
```

`data` is an array-like object, so we call `slice` on it first to return an array. Next we map each item in the array. This mapping is a sum of all the values of each element in the array, except for `hour`, which is a date, so it gets filtered out of the keys list. The final value of `sums` is an array of totals from each object in `data`.

Comment: thx a lot for the solution i just tried and it works perfectly ! @t.888